# PubSub between servers using HTTP

Tags: asp.net, publish-subscribe

I have two asp.net applications, one of which is a publisher of data, one is a subscriber. It's possible there will be more subscribers too. The list is not anonymous, I know my applications.

What would be the best strategy to notify the subscribers when there is data in the publisher?

There are several message brokers and queueing systems on the internet, most are hard to implement and require code that I don't really find desirable (for instance running a service on the machines of the applications, where the services do the communication).

I don't mind running a server somehow that brokers messages, like a hub, but I would prefer a hub that offers an HTTP API I can call from my publisher, and that calls an HTTP page on the subscribers (kind of like PubSubHubbub but that appears to be very much about RSS feeds).

It's a bit unfeasable to write my own queueing system because there are some hard problems in that as well. Also calling the list of subscribers from publisher directly will cause some performance issues that I also want to avoid.

Do you know of solutions I can try?

PS: if this message is better suited for Programmers@StackExchange, feel free to move it!